# Google calendar How to edit recurring event through php api?

Tags: google-calendar-api, recurring-events

How to update instance of recurring event using php api
and perform following.

1.This only
2.This and following
3.All Events

For Weekly recurring events.

Also Can u help for how to make , DOES NOT REPEAT for above options..

Comment: Please [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/43463046/edit) the question to be on-topic: include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that duplicates the problem. Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working the way I want?") must include: (1) the desired behavior, (2) a specific problem or error and (3) the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Please also see: [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), and [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

Please read the documentation on recurring events first and then further specify what you tried and what did not work:

https://developers.google.com/calendar/concepts/events-calendars#recurring_events

and

https://developers.google.com/calendar/recurringevents